# Elmah not emailing Exceptions in MVC3, but will email page errors, 404, etc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, smtp, elmah

I cannot figure this out. Elmah isn't logging exceptions that happen inside a Controller. For example, no email is generated for this:

```
  [Authorize]
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Reply(ReplyViewModel viewModel)
    {

      throw new Exception("Test");
     ....
    }
```

Web.config looks like this:

```
configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="elmah">
      <section name="security" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorLog" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorMail" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorMailSectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorFilter" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterSectionHandler, Elmah" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>


  <elmah>
    <!--<errorLog type="Elmah.SqlErrorLog, Elmah" connectionStringName="elmah-sql"   >
    </errorLog>-->
    <errorMail from="somewhere@somewhere.com"
       to="errors@somewhere.com"
       subject="Error Subject Line"
       async="true"
       smtpPort="25"
       smtpServer="ourstmpserver">
    </errorMail>
  </elmah>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
    <membership>
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <profile>
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <roleManager enabled="false">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
        <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
    <httpModules>
      <!--<add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" />-->
      <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" />
      <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" />
    </httpModules>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
    </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <!--<add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />-->
      <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <add name="Elmah" path="elmah.axd" verb="POST,GET,HEAD" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" preCondition="integratedMode" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

But, if I navigate to a URL for which I have no Controller/Action, I will get an email from Elmah.

What gives? I really need emails when Exceptions happen...

Comment: Does elmah log the error? That is, if you go to your reply action, and see a ysod or whatever, can you see the exception in the log at the /elmah.axd handler URL?

Comment: Have you tried setting customErrors mode to Off ? I've found lately the same problem and errors started appear in Elmah when I've switched that

Comment: Custom errors are off. Still nothing.

Comment: @olivehour It doesn't log the exception AT ALL. I changed it to in-memory log because we're not actually concerned with logging, just the email of the exception. When it hits that exception I am throwing ON PURPOSE in the controller, Elmah does NOTHING. It's weird.

Comment: Sorry, I should have noticed that. Just to be clear, if you uncomment the errorlog modules, it does not log at all either?

Comment: Nope @olivehour. I uncommented all those, still nothing from Elmah.

Comment: hi, did you resolve your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using Elmah.Contrib.Mvc available on NuGet.

We use this package, and register their HandleErrorAttribute in our Global.asax, like so:

```
private static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    //filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute()); // default MVC setting
    filters.Add(new ElmahHandleErrorAttribute()); // from Elmah.Contrib.Mvc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem, and eventually solved it by using the source for debugging: [Download Source](http://elmah.googlecode.com/files/ELMAH-1.2-sp2-src.zip)

In my case, `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` was replaced by a `CurrentPrincipal` with `Identity = null`, which caused an Exception, since Elmah is using `CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name`.

All exceptions inside Elmah itself are catched to prevent your program from crashing as a result of a logging exception, in which case the original Exception is also lost.

This is just an example of what went wrong in my case, any exception caused in Elmah itself will result in this behavior. Therefore the source should be used to debug. An alternative could be to look at the Trace, since Elmah is writing any catched exceptions to the Trace.